# Conducting anova based on preconditions? Too many hypotheses?

Tags: regression, anova

Can you please help clarify what type of test I should be using - 
The hypothesis is - where clinicians have rated the participant as x, and the participants have scored above 62 on questionnaire for shyness, there will be a significant difference between the means of scores on the dependent variable pre and post. (The participants are using an intervention and completing a questionnaire before and after which is scored)

Other quick question- for an ethics application with a mixed methods exploratory feasibility design can there be too many hypotheses? I've got 6 quantitative and 10 qualitative.

Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First question: You can use a paired t-test to see if there is difference in the mean.

Second question:  It might be that you reject (at least) one of your null hypothesis when you add more hypothesis just by chance (also depends on your rejection level)

Comment: So would I need to set things up in SPSS before computing the paired t test? For example selecting only certain cases based on those stipulations (clinicians rating and score on shyness questionniare)?

Comment: In order to answer you RQ yes. But I would also do the same test with the other subjects (the ones that are not part of your hypothesis) so that you can see if there is a differrnce between these two groups. You can also back that up with a statistical test (t-test for two means for example) in which you compare the mean pre post difference of both groups then. This is then basically including a control group.